# How can I programmatically launch Contacts.app on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I would like to launch the Contacts.app when the user needs to add a contact.  My app already reads from the contact API.  I would rather not re-implement functionality if I can avoid it.  I am targeting iOS 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a contact, use [ABNewPersonViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABNewPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See [Interacting Using UI Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/400-UI_Controllers/UI_Controllers.html) for full details on this and the other AB UIViewControllers.

Comment: +1 why launch another app when you can do it for free in the same one?

Comment: for iOS 9+, this is deprecated now. The new way is CNContactViewController's [viewControllerForNewContact](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui/cncontactviewcontroller/1616922-viewcontrollerfornewcontact?language=objc) method.